# Дата в нужном формате

Tags: php

Как вывести дату в таком формате: `14th October, 2018`, есть такой код:

```
$timestamp = strtotime("14 October 2018");
$newDate = date("d F, Y", $timestamp);
echo $newDate;
```

Но как добавить `th`, чтобы было `14th`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про форматы даты можно почитать [здесь](http://www.php.su/date). В вашем случае попробуйте:

```
$newDate = date("jS F, Y", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте формат S для суффикса. Он применяется только с j - форматом дня без ведущего нуля.

```
 $newDate = date("jS F, Y", $timestamp);
```

Подробнее [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php).